# Power supply design issue

Tags: power-supply

[image: Power supply]

Hi!

I have PCB with this schematic and when it's power on, output is 0 V. As I understand there is not correct connection for IC1 ground. So my question is how to make it work? C19 make short and remove C6? Do I remove L3 and L4 too?

Comment: Texas Instruments give you examples on how to use their device and pcb layout. You’d be best following their advice. Removing C19 would be a start, but i’d think if that made it to the pcb, then the pcb layout would be compromised.

Comment: What happens if you remove Z1?

Comment: Yes, the GND pin and all the stuff connected to it needs to be solidly linked to GND_Rst. You might be able to do it by shorting C19 if the PCB layout is good enough.

Comment: I removed C6 and leave open, removed C19 and short it. Right now it works. Z1 is for enable,  to save EN pin for not higher input as 5V.